# java filter by dynamic set

Tags: java, filter, functional-programming

Hi I am new to java functional programming. I am trying to filter a map, if element is in the set, skip it; else process it and put it in the set.
But I found it looks like the set keeps static (not updated by the terminal operation)

```
public class StreamMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, String> HOSTING = new HashMap<>();
        HOSTING.put(1, "linode.com");
        HOSTING.put(2, "heroku.com");
        HOSTING.put(3, "digitalocean.com");
        HOSTING.put(4, "aws.amazon.com");
        HOSTING.put(5, "aws.amazon.com");

        Set<String> s = new HashSet();

        //Map -> Stream -> Filter -> Map
        HOSTING.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(map -> !s.contains(map.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue())).forEach((k, v) -> {System.out.println("show:" + String.valueOf(k)  + v);s.add(v);});


    }
}
```

It returns

```
show:linode.com
show:heroku.com
show:digitalocean.com
show:aws.amazon.com
show:aws.amazon.com //I don't want this to be returns because it's already done before
```

Comment: `s` is an empty set, what do you expect about that?

Comment: I put the processed element in the sets.add(v);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something lie this:

```
    HOSTING.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(map -> s.add(map.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue())).forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println("show:" + v);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is you can convert your map values to the list, and then you can use **Distinct()** over the list easily

```
 List<String> result = HOSTING.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); //convert map to list
 result.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());  // filtering the list

 System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I still need a map in the println method.